# RSSI Module - Cannot import name 'RSSI_Localizer' from partially initialized module 'rssi'

Tags: python, python-3.x, rssi

I'm using the exact GIT example of the project (https://pypi.org/project/rssi/) , and I'm getting this error.

The code I'm using is this:

```
from rssi import RSSI_Localizer


accessPoints = [{
         'signalAttenuation': 3, 
         'location': {
             'y': 1, 
             'x': 1
         }, 
         'reference': {
             'distance': 4, 
             'signal': -50
         }, 
         'name': 'dd-wrt'
     },
     {
         'signalAttenuation': 4, 
         'location': {
             'y': 1, 
             'x': 7
         }, 
         'reference': {
             'distance': 3, 
             'signal': -41
         }, 
         'name': 'ucrwpa'
     }]

accessPoint = {
     'signalAttenuation': 3, 
     'location': {
         'y': 1, 
         'x': 1
     }, 
     'reference': {
         'distance': 4, 
         'signal': -50
     }, 
     'name': 'dd-wrt'
}

signalStrength = -69

rssi_localizer_instance = RSSI_Localizer(accessPoints=accessPoints)
```

And I'm getting this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'RSSI_Localizer' from partially initialized module 'rssi' (most likely due to a circular import)

The version of Python I'm using is: Python 3.11.6

Has anyone ever experienced this ?

Comment: Is this script itself named `rssi.py` ?

Comment: Yes! You are right! Sorry and Thanks!